# ¿como hago para agregar un espacio despues de cada item de un array automaticamente?

Tags: array

hice una aplicacion de números primos donde podes ingresar un limite en un input y te dice los números primos hasta ese número. hice un array vacío y una función para validar si determinado número es primo o no, si es primo lo agrega al array automáticamente.

este es el codigo que use:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El problema es que como se agregan automáticamente, no se como hacer para que después de la coma que viene despues de cada elemento haya un espacio y como no hay espacios no puedo hacer que el texto siga abajo y queda asi:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
como pueden ver el texto se sale de la caja. ya intende con "wrap", "max-width", etc, pero al no tener espacios nada funciona.

lo que necesito es hacer que automaticamente despues de cada elemento se agregue un espacio.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5080165/join-an-array-by-a-comma-and-a-space

Answer (score 0):

Varias cosas;

- En la función "primesUpto", el "forEach" no haría nada, ya que está vacio en ese punto.
- Estas devolviendo un array a un elemento HTML, y no sé cómo no te da error.

Yo lo que haría, sería reemplazar el array "allResult" de la función "primesUpto", y colocar un string, algo como;

```
miString += i + ", ";
```

En el bucle del for.

Al final, y antes de retornar, quitaría la última coma y espacio con;

```
miString.substring(0, miString.length-2);
```

Saludos